# C++: Instantiate same object as one of many types depending on variable

Tags: c++, object, switch-statement, delete-operator

I am programming an LED Cube I have designed. The cube has a "pause" button and a "play/next" button. Unless the cube is paused, it will cycle through all of the different effects (animations) I've made for it. If you press the pause button, the cube will no longer transition between effects and will instead repeat the current effect. Pressing the 'play/next' button will unset the pause feature and will advance to the next effect immediately.

Some of these effects are pretty complex and require a large number of variables to be kept between frames of animation. In order to easily destroy all of these variables at a moment's notice (like when the next button is pressed), I'm instantiating the current animation as an object and destroying it when the effect is complete or the skip button is pressed.

I'm trying to set my main loop up as follows:

```
void loop() {
  //create an effect object
  switch(effectIndex){
    case 0:
    EF_GROWFRAME effect;
    break;
    case 1:
    EF_RANDOMFILL effect;
    break;
  }

  bool proceed;

  do{
    //returns false until the effect has completed
    proceed=effect.step();
    //push this cube update and wait for it to display
    cube.update();
    cube.waitForFrame();
  }
  while ((!proceed)&&(!skipflag));
  //skipflag is set true during a timer interrupt if the skip button is freshly pressed
  skipflag=false;
  cube.clearPattern();

  if (play) effectIndex++;
  if (effectIndex=effectCount) effectIndex=0;
}
```

That fails because of my conflicting definitions of `effect` though. You can probably see what I'm going for, so what's the proper way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a use case for polymorphism.

Define a base class, `Animation` that defines a shared interface and have your various animation types derive from it.  For example:

```
class Animation {
public:
    virtual ~Animation() {
        // any generic cleanup shared by all animation types
    }
    virtual bool step() = 0;
};

class AnimationA : public Animation {
public:
    bool step() override {
        // logic for this type of animation
    }
};

class AnimationB : public Animation {
public:
    bool step() override {
        // logic for this type of animation
    }
};

void loop() {
    std::unique_ptr<Animation> effect;

    switch (effectIndex) {
    case 0:
        effect = std::make_unique<AnimationA>();
        break;
    case 1:
        effect = std::make_unique<AnimationB>();
        break;
    }

    //...
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e51d78147886279)

---

Since it seems like this may be an embedded environment, you could avoid the dynamic memory allocation from my first example by factoring your animation playing logic out into a separate function:

```
void playAnimation(Animation& effect) {
    bool proceed;

    do{
        //returns false until the effect has completed
        proceed=effect.step();
        //push this cube update and wait for it to display
        cube.update();
        cube.waitForFrame();
    } while (!proceed && !skipFlag);
    //skipflag is set true during a timer interrupt if the skip button is freshly pressed
    skipflag=false;
    cube.clearPattern();
}

void loop() {
    switch (effectIndex) {
    case 0:
        {
            AnimationA effect;
            playAnimation(effect);
            break;
        }
    case 1:
        {
            AnimationB effect;
            playAnimation(effect);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (play) effectIndex++;
    if (effectIndex == effectCount) effectIndex=0;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b74b966d3d43c002)

Comment: I read your answer, tried to implement `unique_ptr`, researched Arduino's incompatibility with the <memory> header for about an hour, and then found and implemented your edit. If I could give you an upvote twice, I gladly would. Thank you.